# XSLT transform will not correctly output HTML img tag

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to create an HTML page that is an image map of a building with people's names and pictures taken from an XML file and placed on the map at specific coordinates (defined by CSS). Here is the XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/dataset/custodians">
        <html>
        <head>

        <title>
        </title>

        </head>
        <body>

        <xsl:for-each select='custodian'>
        <p>
           <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="location"/></xsl:attribute>
           <xsl:attribute name="class">custodian</xsl:attribute>
           <br/>
            <div>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">hover_img</xsl:attribute>
                 <a>
                  <xsl:attribute name="href">#</xsl:attribute>
                 <span>
                   <img>
                        <xsl:attribute name="src"> <xsl:value-of select="pic"> </xsl:value-of> </xsl:attribute>
                    </img>
                 </span></a>
            </div>
           <br/>
           <xsl:value-of select="name"></xsl:value-of>
           <br/>
           <xsl:value-of select="location_string"></xsl:value-of>
           <br/>
           <xsl:value-of select="phone"></xsl:value-of>
        </p>

        </xsl:for-each>

        </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I run the XSL file against this XML file:

```
<dataset>   
<custodians>
    <custodian>
      <name> Person 1 </name>
      <location>location1_004</location>
      <location_string>1-004</location_string>
      <pic>H:\path\to\image1.jpg</pic>
      <phone>861-6969</phone>
    </custodian>
    <custodian>
      <name> Person 2 </name>
      <location>location1_027</location>
      <location_string>1-027</location_string>
      <pic>H:\path\to\image2.jpg</pic>
      <phone>861-6868</phone>
    </custodian> 
 </custodians>
</dataset>
```

The output that I am getting shows the names down the side of the screen, instead of on the map in their proper location. Everything worked fine until I started trying to add the images to the XSL file.

What am I doing wrong in the XSL file?

Comment: Well, firstly a bit of style and readability: why write `<p><xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="location"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="class">custodian</xsl:attribute>` when you could write `<p id="{location}" class="custodian">`?

Comment: Show us the HTML you want to generate that renders the image map correctly. Then show us the HTML you are actually generating.

Comment: So where is the CSS that you say you use that is failing?

Comment: Is the issue because you are using a file system path to the image `H:\path\to\image1.jpg`? If you are viewing the web page in a web browser, it will look for the image on the client PC (although I don't think it will serve it up even if it did exist). If the image only exists on the web server, you should be using a relative URL (relative to the HTML page being viewed), or maybe a full URL, like `http://localhost/mywebsite/images/image1.jpg`.

Comment: The image actually show up fine when I use a local file system image. This is a locally run html file, btw. I changed the image to point to a random jpg on the internet and it also behaves the same way as the local image.